# Algorithm to find a windows domain (AD) in the network

Tags: dns, active-directory, windowsdomainaccount

I need an algorithm to find if there is a windows domain (AD service) set up in the network I am currently connected to. This should work for any network (a WiFi in McDonald's or a corporate network) meaning I do not know the name of the domain I am looking for (if there is any).

All I have ever found were ways to check for the domain my computer is in. That is not what I want.

I can perform simple queries (DNS, ...) and this algorithm shall work from any operating system (meaning no readings from windows registry).

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get a DomainConntroller you must get the "domain" of the network first. And this can not be done, as far as I found, just by DNS reqests.